# Error on making resumeable download in c#

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpresponse

I was trying to test a resumable download using c#. I found that add range will help by looking at some blogs. But in the following code **add range** have no meaning. 
Guys Suggest me how to solve the issue. 
What method will be effective to make a Resumable download??

```
HttpWebRequest myrequest = null;
    HttpWebResponse myresponse = null;
    private int interval=2048;
    public bool set_url(string todonwloads,string tosaves)
    {
        this.todownload = todonwloads;
        this.tosave = tosaves;
        return true;
    }
    public bool start_download()
    {
        myrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.todownload);
       // it the following code. 
       //If i dont write addrange. It will download same portion of the file.
        myrequest.AddRange(4000,8000);

        try
        {
            myresponse = (HttpWebResponse)myrequest.GetResponse();
            if (myresponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream ReceiveSteam = myresponse.GetResponseStream();
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(
                                        this.tosave, 
                                        FileMode.Create, 
                                        FileAccess.Write, 
                                        FileShare.None);
                int reads;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[this.interval];
                while ((reads = ReceiveSteam.Read(
                                         buffer, 
                                         0, 
                                         this.interval)) > 0)
                {
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, reads);
                }
                return true;
            }


        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myresponse != null)
            {
                myresponse.Close();
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently create and overwrite the file every time you download a section of the file:

```
//            Overwrites the file each time -\/
... = new FileStream(this.tosave, FileMode.Create, ...
```

You instead need to *open or create* the file using `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, then seek to the last section of the file you wrote to:

```
// seek to the last end offset, you'll need to save this somehow
fs.Seek(lastOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);

int reads;
byte[] buffer = new byte[this.interval];
while ((reads = ReceiveSteam.Read(buffer, 0, this.interval)) > 0)
{
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, reads);
    lastOffset += reads;
}
```

Comment: yaa. I got that. But the what i wanted to ask was for downloading. Even when i inserted add range in the code. The application downloads all part of it and write to file..

Comment: [The server may not support the Range header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fy67z6d.aspx). Try printing `myresponse.Headers.ToString()` to see if it has `Accept-Ranges: bytes`.